# How to automate custom designed browser based application?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

We have an JavaScript application which runs on our own custom designed browser. Now, I have came across the situation to automate our application on that browser.

I have vast experience in Selenium Webdriver using Java. But it doesn't automate it.

Could you please let me know can we automate custom designed browser using selenium. If yes please explain.

or

Is there any open source tool to automate it using Java as scripting language.

I have tried Sikuli but it is very slow. Please suggest something else.

I also heard about Google Window Tester Pro. Will it do for me. If yes please let me know how to setup it in eclipse.

Thanks in advance..